# Is this possible to exclude html elements/components from a Vuetify v-form?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using vuetify VForm component to add validation on inputs, but I also to put forms to "readonly" (with the readonly prop).

My problem is that I have some inputs that I don't want to be "readonly".

Sadly It's not possible to override the VForm readonly with a VTextField readonly to false :

```
<v-form readonly>
   <v-text-field
      :readonly="false"  // not working
   </v-text-field>
</v-form>
```

So I'm asking if anyone has an idea to exclude elements from VForm context ?

Comment: I think v-form will take precedence up the text if you want to exclude elements you should have a read-only state for each element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out myself, we just need to wrap editable element in a new VForm that isn't readonly

```
<v-form readonly>

  // not editable
  <v-text-field>
  </v-text-field>


  <v-form>
    // editable
    <v-text-field>
    </v-text-field>
  </v-form>

</v-form>
```